# SQL throwing error when table name contains space and brackets

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the code I used to create the table. I replace `""` with `[]` but the same error gets thrown in to the console

```
CREATE TABLE google_trends_cartier
(
   "Month/Date" VARCHAR(255),
   "Cartier (Jeweler) China" INT,
   "cartier (Search Term) China" INT,
   "Cartier (Jeweler) United States" INT,
   "cartier (Search Term) United States" INT,

);
```

Error message is given below

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Month/Date" VARCHAR(255),
   "Cartier (Jeweler) China" INT,
   "cartier (Search' at line 3
mysql> CREATE TABLE google_trends_cartier (    "Month/Date" VARCHAR(255),    "Cartier (Jeweler) China" INT,    "cartier (Search Term) China" INT,    "Cartier (Jeweler) United States" INT,    "cartier (Search Term) United States" INT,  );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Month/Date" VARCHAR(255),    "Cartier (Jeweler) China" INT,    "cartier (Search' at line 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Tip: Do not include spaces, parentheses, or mathematical operators in table/column identifiers. Indeed, inclusion of mathematical operators is a cataclysmically bad idea.

Comment: Also, you appear to be designing a spreadsheet - the antithesis of a database table.

Comment: "cartier (Search Term) United States" INT,   please remove the comma

Comment: why, is there anything wrong with the syntax? @Sergey

Comment: it is the last column in the table (at least in the provided script)

Comment: but removing that still throws errors @Sergey

Comment: Horrible data model, will cause many problems in the near future. What if you also want to store some data from the UK? New columns are needed and this proves that your data model has serious issues. And then some data from Brazil, same problem, again... Try to create a 3NF model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: I'll remove the PostgreSQL tag. In a standard compliant database your statement would work.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways around the problem of column names with spaces and (some) punctuation, but here's the far better solution.

```
CREATE TABLE google_trends_cartier
(
    yr INT,
    mo INT,
    cartier_jeweler_china INT,
    cartier_term_china INT,
    cartier_jeweler_us INT,
    cartier_term_us INT
);
```

Trust us. You will thank us later.

Answer (score -1):

I recently faced a similar error. Try enclosing the literal string in backtick, ` .

Comment: Just... just don't .

Comment: Is there a reason why this can’t be used in the context of this question? Will this not work for parentheses? I am not debating your comment around not using such characters but am just curious if it would work or not!

Comment: It would work but I agree... just don't. It's a cancer to anyone who has to maintain or work on the DB. Anything where you are forced to enclose something in identifier quotes is a pain. That includes spaces, capitals, and special characters. Use snake case only.